# How to queue up transactions in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm building a mobile App which is multiply functions. I have three buttons in my page. This buttons run same function with different parameters. Every button spend some times(10sn) to get response from request(axios). Users can push buttons one after the other in a a few second. Therefore, I want to queue the processes when I press the buttons one after the other. Whichever button I pressed first, that action should be done, then the other action should be done. It's like a temporary memory operation. Do you know any way to do it?

[image: My buttons on page]

Comment: Have you tried something already ? Could be a starting point.

Comment: I can think of plenty of ways to do this but i don’t think anything is going to work “out of the box”, the simplest way I can think of would be to store request data in an array and keep track of when requests start & finish, when one finishes if there are requests pending in the array fire off the next item etc.

Comment: The “proper” way might be to build out a linked queue which is more or less a fancy array but more structured, really depends on the level of complexity you’re willing to deal with and whether this is something integral to the app.